# What is wrong with the ngFor?

Tags: angular

I can't understand why the following code doesn't work

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let caregory of this.service.response">
      {{ category.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

while this one works

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let caregory of this.service.response; let i = index">
      {{ this.service.response[i].name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simple typo - you have `category` spelled wrong in your `ngFor` - you have `caregory`

Comment: share code from your .ts file as well. If you're using `this.service.response` on the html you should use `service.response` also type in your code as @tym

Comment: I believe that you might have duplicates in your array. That is why it works only when you start tracking the array object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

category spelling mistake

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let category of this.service.response">
      {{ category.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: xd ok that was an ultimate fail :P

Answer (score 0):

It's just small typo ! 
If you want to use "caregory " then

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let caregory of this.service.response">
      {{ caregory .name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

else if you want to use "category" then,

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let category of this.service.response">
      {{ category .name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```